# Can there be a "subscribe to newsletter" link on about or faq pages?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, newsletter

I was browsing boardgames.se and thought that I'd like to get the newsletter.   I had to go to meta and search for how to find it because I didn't see the advertisement for the newsletter and it wasn't linked on the faq or the about page.

Can we add a link to subscribe to the newsletter from one of those pages?

Comment: I really think this needs to be in a different place. I never would have thought to have gone to my profile to subscribe to the site. And had I looked there, I never would have thought to edit my profile. Neither would I have thought to go to my network profile to subscribe to the newsletter for the specific site that I was just on. Subscribing to the newsletter is something that I change about the site (like favoriting a tag), not changing something about me.

Answer (score 4):

You can get at newsletter subscriptions in a couple ways.

The randomly shown sidebar ads.
[image]

On your user edit page.
[image]

And on StackExchange.com.
[image]

For now, I don't think putting a link on the faq/about page is necessary.

Comment: Thanks. This helped me, and encouraged me to ask a proposed FAQ stealing, and write an answer based closely on this. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121631/how-do-i-subscribe-for-a-sites-weekly-email-newsletter

Comment: This is really not obvious enough. I had to google for "Stackexchange Newsletter". Hope SE put it in a better place.