# How do I subscribe for a site's weekly email newsletter?

Tags: support, newsletter

I have heard about the weekly newsletter. How do I subscribe?

Comment: This question is motivated by the fact there is nothing at all in the [common FAQ](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)'s or the [FAQ for StackExchange Sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) about newsletters. Also because it is genuinely hard to find the subscribe button. See [related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121630/what-is-the-weekly-newsletter-who-composes-them) and a [similar, but different, request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101954/can-there-be-a-subscribe-to-newsletter-link-on-about-or-faq-pages).

Comment: [There will be an occasional sidebar ad if you haven't signed up yet.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96758/weekly-site-newsletters)

Comment: Daniel: Yes, but I realised 30 minutes ago I wasn't subscribed, *even though I am a mod!* I tried to rectify that, and realised that despite being very familiar with the site, I had no idea how to do it! That was embarrassing enough, but being unable to find it in any of the FAQs made it worse.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get at newsletter subscriptions three different ways.

### User Edit Page

Click on your username at the top of the page to go to your user profile page. From there, click Edit to see the option to subscribe to the current site's newsletter.

[image: User Edit page excerpt]

### Master StackExchange list

Via your Network Profile page, you can click on Newsletters.

[image]

That will take you to the [Newsletters page](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) where you can see all the possible newsletters, and to which ones you subscribe.

### Sidebar Ads

Sometimes, the adverts on the sidebar on the right of the question pages will show an advert that can be clicked on.

[image: Advert for newsletter]

[Hat tip to @KevinMontrose for [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/103004/145319) to a similar question.]

Comment: I never would have thought to have gone to my profile to subscribe to the site. And had I looked there, I never would have thought to edit my profile. Neither would I have thought to go to my network profile to subscribe to the newsletter for the specific site that I was just on. Subscribing to the newsletter is something that I change about the site (like favoriting a tag), not changing something about me.

Comment: How can I receive to feedly? Any rss way?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [page](https://stackexchange.com/newsletters) where you can get list of all sites you can subscribe to